# Using one dimmer to control 2 sets of lights with each an On/Off Switch

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch

I want to install some LED lights in my RV. I have 2 sets of 4 LEDs, connected on my 12V circuit. One set is for the front (kitchen area), one set in the back (living area). When all the lights are opens (both switches), I want them to be controlled by one dimmer to have the same intensity through the whole RV. I also want to be able to shut off one of the area independently.

Is that possible? Would the dimmer be wired up front, and from it connect both switches that runs to each set of LEDs in series?

Thank you for your help!

John

Comment: Yes but not easily since LEDs don’t share current or voltage

Comment: compatible topology depends on the way the LEDs are built, but it sounds like you need a couple smart light controllers that can sync with each other, then you don't have to worry about fancy wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's fine, have a master dimmer then 2 switches deciding which LEDs are on.

However the LEDs and the dimming method must be compatible. Generally with 12V you use PWM dimming.  Make sure you select LED lights which are friendly to PWM dimming, i.e. Have a simple resistor regulator instead of a switching power supply.  If the bulb says "works on 12-24V" it's a switching power supply type, which will treat attempted dimming as dirty power, and attempt to compensate for it.

IKEA comes to mind as a source for architectural grade LED fixtures made for PWM dimming.